# Why are some methods that return a Task not marked as Async in generic repository pattern

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, ef-core-2.0

I was reading a really cool article about creating a generic Async repository using the following link https://blog.zhaytam.com/2019/03/14/generic-repository-pattern-csharp/  The interface defines all operations as tasks but the implementation chooses not to use the async/await pattern on a few methods. I'd like to further my understanding of this so decided to post on here.  At first glance, it would seem like the client may not know they need to wait for methods that are not marked async, but I probably don't understand this correctly.  Can anyone comment as to why the author choose not to use async on some methods that return a task and not others?

```
public interface IAsyncRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{

    Task<T> GetById(int id);
    Task<T> FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    Task Add(T entity);
    Task Update(T entity);
    Task Remove(T entity);

    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll();
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    Task<int> CountAll();
    Task<int> CountWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

}

public class EfRepository<T> : IAsyncRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{

    #region Fields

    protected DataDbContext Context;

    #endregion

    public EfRepository(DataDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    #region Public Methods

    public Task<T> GetById(int id) => Context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);

    public Task<T> FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        => Context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);

    public async Task Add(T entity)
    {
        // await Context.AddAsync(entity);
        await Context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public Task Update(T entity)
    {
        // In case AsNoTracking is used
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public Task Remove(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        return Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return await Context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> CountAll() => Context.Set<T>().CountAsync();

    public Task<int> CountWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) 
        => Context.Set<T>().CountAsync(predicate);

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Install [AsyncFixer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SemihOkur.AsyncFixer). Be surprised how many unnecessary async/await. It is a common mistake to insert extra async/await.

Comment: In the example above, `Add` needs to be async because it has two await statements. `Remove` should not be async, because it's not awaiting anything - instead it calls another method and just forwards the Task object created by that method. `GetAll/GetWhere` is likely a mistake - it should not have an `async` or an `await` because it doesn't do anything with the value it awaited except return it. It would be more efficient to just return the Task returned by `ToListAsync`. The current code instead awaits that Task, and then creates a new Task to hold the value it just got out of the first task.

Comment: These comments were super helpful.  I installed the AsyncFixer and it found many cases where they were unnecessary and helped me to see why.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the methods have `async` also have `await`. In those methods you wait for the to execute to obtain the result, meanwhile in those methods without `await` you don't care when they will be executed

Comment: Thanks, but that part I understand.  I'm wondering why the author chose to use/not use async selectively.  I thought that maybe the use of async was only when the task returned a Task<TSomething> but he didn't use Async when returning a count on two methods.

Comment: @Geekn If you don't have an `await` in your method, the method should not be flagged `async` even if it returns a Task. In fact, you'll get a compiler/IDE warning if you create an `async` method that doesn't contain an `await`. It's more efficient for methods that don't wait on the result of a task to just forward the task object along, in which case they don't need to be `async` at the compiler level.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that it was an accidental omission.

I am having a hard time seeing any benefit to awaiting some of the base class methods and not the others.

Comment: On the contrary, it was an erroneous addition. Many of the async/await in that code are not needed.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - true.  My point was the author needs to pick one for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Using ONLY the code presented, with the exception of the `public async Task Add(T entity)` method, the utilisation of "async/await" seems to be completely random.

In all cases, you can either transform the method to `async` and put a `await` right before returning, OR you can remove the `async` and `awaits` and return the `Task`.

In the end, the result is the same, both in terms of compiled code as in behaviour in run-time (performance mostly)

Comment: I ran that async/await fixer tool as suggested and it appeared to show me that any awaitable call that is made where the result is not used should simply return the task and allow the caller to await it if they want.  That makes sense to me as it seems to just add another thread to the call where it's not really needed adding to the possibility of thread starvation and overhead where there doesn't need to be.

Comment: Technically speaking, as I mentioned before, the results are the same, including the number of spawned threads. the `await` keyword alone does not actually causes a await, but rather signal that the following code should not be executed until that call completes. In async cenarios where parallel operations are being executed, it's rather common to have a await not blocking at all because of concurrent operations consuming the CPU!